# clear cache and memory after using NSdata to download a PDF

Tags: iphone, objective-c, caching, nsdata

How would I go about cleaning the cache data and other memory while using this code?
CFData (store) on simulator keeps on growing....

```
-(void)downloadFile:(NSURL *)theURL
{
    NSLog(@"dowbload this url : %@",theURL);

    NSURL *url = theURL;

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDF2.pdf"];

    [data writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];

    [self showThePDF];
    NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
    [sharedCache removeAllCachedResponses];
    [sharedCache release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem to this recently.

Essentially dataWithContentsOfURL is using NSURLConnection under the hood, which caches the response.

I would recommend a couple of things:

Use NSURLConnection yourself to get the data instead of dataWithContentsOfURL.

Use the async NSURLConnection API and delegate methods (there's rarely a need for sync methods).

Implement the NSURLConnection delegate method below and return nil in it:

```
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse *)cachedResponse
{
    return nil;
}
```

This ensures the responses are not cached.

NSURLConnection documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Using NSURLConnection:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

I have the same problem with dataWithContentsOfURL. Try to add @autorealse:

```
            @autoreleasepool {
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSData *data=[[NSData alloc] init];
            data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
            img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            }
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to release the variables: *data*, *paths* and *pdfPath*. The following calls:

```
   [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]

   NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains

   [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DPR2.pdf"]
```

all return owned objects that you need to release in order to avoid memory leaks. You did not call init on them yourself but their internal implementations allocated memory on your behalf, then *retained* this memory (which is why you can use those vars without worrying about getting a segmentation fault). Even though your *variables* go out of scope when the method returns, the *memory* they allocated is being retained because you didn't decrement its reference count via ***release***. I show roughly modified code before that should work:

```
-(void)downloadFile:(NSURL *)theURL 
{ 
    NSLog(@"dowbload this url : %@",theURL); 

    NSURL *url = theURL; 

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DPR2.pdf"]; 

    [data writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES]; 

    [self showThePDF]; 
    NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil]; 
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache]; 
    [sharedCache removeAllCachedResponses]; 
    [sharedCache release];

    [pdfPath release];
    [paths release];
    [data release];
}
```

You can optionally choose to manage your dynamically allocated variables in an [NSAutoReleasePool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Wow, ok so someone downvoted my answer. Care to leave comments about what you disagree with?

Comment: It was not me down voting, nevertheless I don't see why I should release the items since I don't init them nor copy them. 
furthermore, the above code you posted will crash for the same reason, maybe you would like to elaborate on why releasing something I did not allocated.

Comment: Dear Perception, I disagree and the code crashes just to prove me right, try it yourself and you will see. I thank you for your time, nevertheless by my understanding you are not correct, a working code will prove me wrong but I rather understand then solve the issue itself.

Comment: I'll try it when I get access to a Mac and edit my answer if indeed, I am incorrect. In the meantime you might want to profile your code to make sure you are releasing all owned objects.

Comment: All those variables are autoreleased and should not be released manually - ShiShi is correct here.